# Implementing Django with ODK Aggregate

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm working on a project where our team is trying to implement Django into the ODK Aggregate platform, we don't quite enjoy their choice of functionality/looks, so we want to create a better template and make it more user-friendly.

We've yet to understand how to upload Django onto the Appengine/Appspot, Aggregate was previously installed on the Appengine, and the Django package was >3000 files, and we got errors when trying to upload the full package.

Does anyone know of a successful implementation of Django with ODK Aggregate specifically?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django10_zipimport.html <-- to see how to upload > "3000" files.

Answer (score 1):

ODK Aggregate is written on Java stack. If you want to use python/Django to make it more user friendly and good looking, it is better to rewrite it completely instead of mixing technologies.

Several ODK Build alternatives are available, neither one of those was built on top of others, so it is not mandatory what you are trying to do as long as you follow the XForms specification.